# How and where can I install threeparttable.sty?

Tags: installing, threeparttable

I want to install threeparttable.sty to add footnotes into tables, but I don't know where and how. I tried by Miktex, but didn't work for an error on connection.

The package is online http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/threeparttable

Thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution;

The following are the steps that you should follow to install a new LaTeX package into your own home directory.

1. Download the package file(s) from wherever they are available. Most packages are available from CTAN; enter appropriate keywords in the search fields to find the files.
2. Packages may be distributed in different ways. Many packages on CTAN, for instance, come with a .dtx file and a .ins file. If the package you are installing comes with these files, you will have to process them with latex to create the actual files that make up the package. That is, type
   latex filename.dtx and/or latex filename.ins
   to unpackage the various .sty and other files in the package.
3. Create a directory texmf in your home directory, if there is not one there already.
4. Install the various package files into subdirectories of texmf as follows:

   ```
   All .bst and .bib files into texmf/bibtex (or subdirectories)
   All font-related files into texmf/fonts (or subdirectories)
   All documentation files into texmf/docs
   All other files (.sty, .cls, .tex, etc.) should go into texmf/tex.
   ```

Alternatively, you could put all of the .sty etc. files into the same directory as the document you are editing. However, if you end up wanting to use them again later, you will have to copy them into the new directory as well, so in the long term it is probably better to put them into ~/texmf.

Comment: MiKTeX has a `Package Manager` which you should use to install packages. `Threeparttable` is part of `MiKTeX`.